# Stylelint disable rule, "no-descending-specificity" null does not work

Tags: sass, lint, stylelint

Not able to disable the styelint rule "no-descending-specificity" by assigning **null** value within the  stylelintric.json file

```
"rules": {
    "no-descending-specificity": null
 }
```

Instead I had to write the below line to the top of my scss file

```
/* stylelint-disable no-descending-specificity */
```

Stylint [doc](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure/#rules) however allows usage of **null** to turn off any rule. What could be wrong here?

My eslint version is 4.19.1.

Answer (score 4):

> What could be wrong here?

Stylelint may not be using the configuration object that you added  `"no-descending-specificity": null` to.

Check that:

- you only have one `.stylelintrc` file, `stylelint.config.js` file or `stylelint` property in your `package.json` file (see [docs](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure))
- if using a file, ensure it's named correctly, e.g. `.stylelintrc.json` (note the leading period and spelling of the file
  name)
- the file is in the root of your project

A more complete configuration object, should look like:

```
{ 
  "extends": ["stylelint-config-standard"],
  "rules": {
    "no-descending-specificity": null
   }
}
```